# Is the CPU and GPU as desired?

Tags: windows, cpu, performance, operating-systems

Does this system have a 64bit processor and operating system?

[image]

Also is the GPU : *Direct3D 11 & Directx Version 11)* or equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this system have a 64bit processor and operating system?

Obviously, the system is having a 64-bit processor. `Intel Core i5-8400` is the 8th Generation of this processor family. Starting from `Intel Xeon` in June 2004, mostly all processors released by Intel are 64-bit architecture supported. The Wikipedia says:

```
Intel's processors implementing the Intel64 architecture include the Pentium 4 F-series/5x1 
series, 506, and 516, Celeron D models 3x1, 3x6, 355, 347, 352, 360, and 365 and all later 
Celerons, all models of Xeon since "Nocona", all models of Pentium Dual-Core processors since 
"Merom-2M", the Atom 230, 330, D410, D425, D510, D525, N450, N455, N470, N475, N550, N570, 
N2600 and N2800, and all versions of the Pentium D, Pentium Extreme Edition, Core 2, Core i7, 
Core i5, and Core i3 processors.
```

But the 64-bit operating system is dependent. As it is 64-bit processor, it will obviously support a 64-bit operating system. But you have to install a 64-bit operating system into it manually. It is not like if you install any versions of operating system and that will act like 64-bit. Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of popular operating systems are readily available in the market. So, you can choose from there.

> Also is the GPU : Direct3D 11 & Directx Version 11 or equivalent?

Yes, it is more than that. The official [specification page](https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-N105TG1-GAMING-4GD#sp) says that it is having the support of `DirectX 12`. So, it can easily incorporate with the previous versions like `DirectX 11` as well as `Direct3D 11`.